# Keep user signed in using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, cookies, mod-wsgi, sign

I'm developing a web app using my own framework that I created using mod_wsgi.

I want to avoid using dependencies such as Django or Flask, just to have a short script, It actually won't be doing much.

I have managed to authenticate user using LDAP, from a login page, the problem is that I don't want the user to authenticate every time a action requires authorization, but I don't know how to keep user logged in.

Should I use the cookies? If so, what would be the best method to keep identification in cookies? What are my options?

Comment: most of the time people use session variables for that ...

Comment: Is the session variable in the cookies? Is there a standard way to do this or should I invent my own encryption method?

Comment: usually its just a token hash that is stored in a cookie with the details staying on the server ...

Comment: Flask is pretty lightweight. Consider using it even for a small script. The overhead is minimal. Or you could even use something smaller like bottle.

Answer (score 1):

The best (read: easiest) way to go about this is with session variables. That said, in lieu of session variable functionality you would get with a framework, you can implement your own basic system.

1) Generate a random Session id

2) send a cookie to browser

3) Json or pickle encode your variables

4a) save encoded string to key-value storage system like redis or memcached with session if as the key, or

4b) save it to a file on the server preferably in /tmp/

Comment: What do you think about saving it in the mysql db?

Comment: That would work but I wouldn't recommend it for anything more than a trivial user load. Every page hit would use precious DB I/O